# SSD for White macbook 2008

Tags: hard-drive, macbook, ssd

I have a white MacBook from early 2008. It needs a hard drive replacement. I was wondering if:

1. Will it be compatible with any SSD in the market today.
2. If not all then which SSDs are compatible?
3. What are the performance issues (if any) with MacBooks in terms of SSDs?
4. Any other suggestions.
5. A good resource to read about HDD and SSD for MacBooks.

I have a White MacBook 2008 with Mac OS X (10.6.4) and4GB RAM

Answer (score 1):

As long as your MacBook can use SATA drives, you should be fine.

You will notice performance issues over time, because OS X does not support the TRIM command, which means you'll have to format and restore the file system periodically (though the exact time frame "depends").

You'll notice at least a 2x performance increase on load times, but taking the above into account, this might slow down dramatically over time.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect it to work.

While macbooks aren't exactly known for having user replaceable parts and Apple likes to restrict supported hardware, the crux of the matter is that the guts of a mac aren't that different from the guts of a PC.  While the macbook might not encourage swapping in alternate hard drives, Apples also makes the mac pro which runs on the same operating system and does expect you to do that kind of thing.

So what we have is basic support in the operating system and commodity hardware that should be compatible; in short, a recipe for a successful upgrade.  That said, I haven't tried this in person.